# How to use in Angular Material List an Item component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to migrate Angular code from Bootstrap to Material design.
I need to show a list of items (for example Cars). I have a car-list component
and car-item component. I want to keep it separate if it's possible.

Unfortunately the resulting list of 10 items is presented as 10 square boxes on one row instead of expected 10 rows.

**My question is: Can I use a separate component inside a `<mat-list-item>`?**

All angular material examples I came across showed *mat-list-item* with ngFor directive and item template code inside  node. That means to move Item functionality into a List.

### Bootstrap version

*car-list-component.html*

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-car-item
      *ngFor="let carItem of cars"
      [car] = "carItem"
    ></app-car-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

*car-item.component.html*

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <a (click)="carDetail(car.id)">
      <span>{{ getMakeLabel(car.make)}} : {{car.carModel.modelName}} </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a (click)="remove(car)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

### My Angular Material version with a separate item template

*car-list.component.html*

```html
<div>
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-car-item
      *ngFor="let carItem of cars"
      [car] = "carItem"
    ></app-car-item>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
</div>
```

**car-item.component.html** does not change.

### Angular Material Example with 'inline' item template.

This is presented in all examples and tutorials on Angular Material. It would work for me, but as I said before if Item(car) is a more complex object than in this example then I want to keep it separately.

*car-list.component.html*

```html
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let car of cars">
      <a style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="carDetail(car.id)">
       <span>{{ getMakeLabel(car.make)}} : {{car.carModel.modelName}} </span>
      </a>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add mat-list-item as the directive to your app-car-item component.
please refer  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blzeb1

```
<mat-list role="list">
    <app-car-item mat-list-item
      *ngFor="let carItem of cars"
      [car] = "carItem"
    ></app-car-item>
 </mat-list>
```

Comment: @Vladimir If my answer helped you, please mark it with a decision.